# Progress dialogue has white background on Lollipop Devices ,

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, progress-bar, progressdialog

I am migrating my application on Android 5.0 i.e. Lollipop devices , I have problem regarding progress dialog , It work perfectly on pre lollipop devices , but on lollipop it has white background  as shown in image [image]

But in pre lollipop devices it is of transparent background 
[image]

Below is my code :

progress.xml in layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:background="@android:color/transparent" >


<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar3"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/myprogress"
        android:minHeight="48dp" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

myprogress.xml in drawable

```
<shape
    android:shape="oval"
    android:useLevel="false" >
    <size
        android:height="48dip"
        android:width="48dip" />

    <gradient
        android:centerColor="#ff001100"
        android:centerY="0.50"
        android:endColor="#ffffffff"
        android:startColor="#ff000000"
        android:type="sweep"
        android:useLevel="false" />
</shape>
```

and in Java i am using like this

```
public ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

  if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            mProgressDialog.cancel();
        }

        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);

        mProgressDialog.show();
        mProgressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress);
```

Comment: change you app theme in the `style.xml` to a dark theme and dialogs should be dark

Comment: i dont want dark dilaog , I want that white background as transparent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem with help of this tutorial 
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/create-a-transparent-progress-dialog-on-android/

I just pass my drawable into this code

```
mProgressDialog = new TransparentProgressDialog(context, **R.drawable.progress**);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

**and rest code is same as in this example.**

Answer (score 5):

Issue was a white background on lollipop.

solution either of the two (both are same though):

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

or

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have a solution now, but if anyone else is experiencing a similar issue; I found that overriding the ProgressDialog's theme in the constructor worked for me. Something like:

```
mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context, ProgressDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
```

Comment: This works but THEME.HOLO.LIGHT is deprecated. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2):

You can also create a style and assign the style to the dialog:

```
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context, R.style.ProgressDialogStyle);
```

The style (in style.xml):

```
<style name="ProgressDialogStyle" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/color_transparent</item>
</style>
```